# Unable to run spark map function that reads a Tuple RDD and returns a Tuple RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a requirement to generate a paired RDD from another paired RDD. Basically, I am trying to write a map function that does the following.

```
RDD[Polygon,HashSet[Point]] => RDD[Polygon,Integer]
```

Here is the code I have written:

Scala Function that iterates over HashSet and adds up a value from the "Point" Object.

```
def outCountPerCell( jr: Tuple2[Polygon,HashSet[Point]] ) : Tuple2[Polygon,Integer] = {
  val setIter = jr._2.iterator()
  var outageCnt: Int = 0
  while(setIter.hasNext()) {
    outageCnt += setIter.next().getCoordinate().getOrdinate(2).toInt
  }
  return Tuple2(jr._1,Integer.valueOf(outageCnt))
}
```

Applying the function on a paired RDD, which is throwing an error:

```
scala> val mappedJoinResult = joinResult.map((t: Tuple2[Polygon,HashSet[Point]]) => outCountPerCell(t))
<console>:82: error: type mismatch;
found   : ((com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Polygon, java.util.HashSet[com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point])) => (com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Polygon, Integer)
required: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function[(com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Polygon, java.util.HashSet[com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point]),?]
       val mappedJoinResult = joinResult.map((t: Tuple2[Polygon,HashSet[Point]]) => outCountPerCell(t))
```

Can someone take a look and see what I am missing, or share any example code that uses custom function inside map() operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the `joinResult` is a `JavaPairRDD` from the Java API. This data structure's `map` is expecting Java type lambdas (`Function`) which are not (at least trivially) interchangeable with Scala lambdas.

So there are two solutions: try to convert the given method into a Java `Function` to be passed to `map` or simply use the Scala RDD as the developers intended:

#### Setup Dummy Data

Here I create some standin classes and make a Java RDD with a similar structure to OP's:

```
scala> case class Polygon(name: String)
defined class Polygon

scala> case class Point(ordinate: Int)
defined class Point

scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

/* More idiomatic method */
def outCountPerCell( jr: (Polygon,java.util.HashSet[Point])) : (Polygon, Integer) =
{
    val count = jr._2.asScala.map(_.ordinate).sum
    (jr._1, count)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

outCountPerCell: (jr: (Polygon, java.util.HashSet[Point]))(Polygon, Integer)

scala> val hs = new java.util.HashSet[Point]()
hs: java.util.HashSet[Point] = []

scala> hs.add(Point(2))
res13: Boolean = true

scala> hs.add(Point(3))
res14: Boolean = true

scala> val javaRDD = new JavaPairRDD(sc.parallelize(Seq((Polygon("a"), hs))))
javaRDD: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD[Polygon,java.util.HashSet[Point]] = org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD@14fc37a
```

#### Use Scala RDD

The underlying Scala RDD can be retrieved from the Java RDD by using `.rdd`:

```
scala> javaRDD.rdd.map(outCountPerCell).foreach(println)
(Polygon(a),5)
```

#### Even better, use `mapValues` with Scala RDD

Since only the second part of the tuples are changing this problem can be cleanly solved with `.mapValues`:

```
scala> javaRDD.rdd.mapValues(_.asScala.map(_.ordinate).sum).foreach(println)
(Polygon(a),5)
```

Comment: Thank you evan058. I tried above method by removing tuple2. I was able to save the function. When tried to invoke the function, it throws below error.                                                                                     `scala> joinResult.map(outCountPerCell(_)).foreach(println)
<console>:82: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => outCountPerCell(x$1))
       joinResult.map(outCountPerCell(_)).foreach(println)`

Comment: My input Paired RDD has a java.util.HashSet and NOT the scala's HashSet. Do you that could cause this problem ?                          `scala> val joinResult = JoinQuery.SpatialJoinQuery(myPointsRDD,myPolygonRDD,true,true)
joinResult: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD[com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Polygon,java.util.HashSet[com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point]] = org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD@3dc4e185`

Comment: @IWonderHow It works for me with the `java.util.HashSet`. What is the type of `joinResult`? Try `println(joinResult.getClass)`

Comment: It is a javaPairRDD.                                                                                              scala> println(joinResult.getClass)
class org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD

Comment: Thanks evan, it worked !! Thank you so much for taking time and helping out. I had to use                                                                                 `import scala.collection.JavaConverters._`   in order to use .asScala

Comment: @IWonderHow no problem! If this post solved your problem, please accept it.